# Doctrine 2 bad mapping in CollectionType

Tags: mysql, symfony, collections, doctrine, mapping

i have problem with doctrine.

I send CREATE

```
{     
    "userAddresses": [
        {
            "id": null,
            "type": "invoice",
            "address": "test 1",
            "city": "Test",
            "zipCode": "11111",
            "mainAddress": true
        },
        {
            "id": null,
            "type": "delivery",
            "address": "test 2",
            "city": "Test",
            "zipCode": "22222",
            "mainAddress": true
        },
        {
            "id": null,
            "type": "delivery",
            "address": "test 3",
            "city": "Test",
            "zipCode": "33333",
            "mainAddress": true
        }    
    ]
}
```

now in database
[image]

now i send EDIT

```
{
    "userAddresses": [
        {
            "id": 10,
            "type": "invoice",
            "address": "test 1",
            "city": "Test",
            "zipCode": "11111",
            "mainAddress": true
        },
        {
            "id": 22,
            "type": "delivery",
            "address": "test 33",
            "city": "Test",
            "zipCode": "33333",
            "mainAddress": true
        }
    ]
}
```

now in database
[image]

row id 21 was deleted, but real was 22 and row id 21 was edited

where is problem with doctrine?

thank you

i dont know where is problem. How can i map it better?

Comment: Don't you need to send each entities ID when editing ?

Comment: sorry i send it, but nothing, in form is "by_reference" => false